# Ember async router: load code async with extra routes

Tags: ember.js

In the new async router you can async load extra code.

```
App.ArticlesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  beforeModel: function() {
    if (!App.Article) {
      return $.getScript('/articles_code.js');
    }
  }
});
```

but what if the async code contains extra routes?
Ember will have generated them. But I need the ones from the async code, not the ones generated and registered by Ember.

I came up with the following solution (but I'm not pleased with it):

```
App.ArticlesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  beforeModel: function(transition) {
    if (!App.Article) {
      var self = this;
      return $.getScript('/articles_code.js')
        .then(function () {
          return self.reRegisterRoutes(transition, "App", "Article"); //register the routes (with naming convention App.Article__________Route) from the loaded modules (dummies have been generated by Ember) and retry the transaction
        });
    }
  },

  reRegisterRoutes: function (transition, namespaceName, nameStartsWith) { 
    this.container.lookup('route:loading').teardownTopLevelView(); //teardown loading view
    var self = this;
    for (var prop in Ember.Namespace.byName(namespaceName).getOwnProperties()) { //[getOwnProperties](https://gist.github.com/adjohu/1817543)
      if (new RegExp(nameStartsWith + '.+Route', 'i').test(prop)) {
        this.reRegisterRoute(prop.replace(/Route$/, "").camelize()); 
      }
    }
    this.router.router.currentParams = transition.params; //set the parameters of the transition to the currentParams of the router
    return transition.retry(); //retry transaction
  },

  reRegisterRoute: function (routeName) {
    var route = this.container.cache.dict['route:' + routeName];
    if (route != undefined) {
      route.destroy(); //destroy generated route
      delete this.container.cache.dict['route:' + routeName]; //GC
      route = this.container.lookup('route:' + routeName); //register the async loaded route
      route.routeName = routeName; //set the routeName
    }
  }
});
```

any suggestions?

**UPDATE** @darshan-sawardekar

I tried your solution end ended up with this:

```
EEPD.RouteMapper.map(function () {
  this.route('home', { path: '/' });
  this.route('logout');
  this.route('login');

  this.resource('ccpr', function () { //ALL NEEDED FOR THE MENU TO WORK
    this.resource('ccprPatients', { path: '/' }, function () {
        this.route('search');
    });
    this.resource('ccprCardioArticles', { path: "/cardioarticles" });
    this.resource('ccprCardiologists', { path: "/cardiologists" });
    this.resource('ccprInfoSession', { path: "/infosession" }, function () {
        this.route('index');
    });
    this.resource('ccprPatientPresence', { path: "/patientpresence" }, function () {
    });
    this.resource('ccprPresenceOverview', { path: "/presenceoverview" });
    this.resource('ccprNextNutritionalAdvices', { path: "/nextnutritionaladvices" });
    this.resource('ccprParameter', { path: "/parameter" });
    this.resource('ccprListStaff', { path: "/liststaff" });
  });
});
```

then in the seperated loaded file

```
EEPD.RouteMapper.map(function () {
  this.resource('ccpr', function () {
    this.resource('ccprPatients', { path: '/' }, function () {
        this.route('search');
    });
    this.resource('ccprPatient', { path: '/:ccpr_patient_id' }, function () {
        this.resource('ccprPracticeSessions', { path: '/practicesessions' }, function () {
        });
        this.resource('ccprPracticeSession', { path: '/practicesessions/:ccpr_practiceSession_id' }, function () {
            this.route('info');
            this.route('anamnese');
            this.route('medication');
            this.route('trainingModel', { path: '/trainingmodel' });
            this.route('socialEvaluation', { path: '/socialevaluation' });
            this.route('medicalFollowUp', { path: '/medicalfollowup' });
            this.resource('ccprPracticeSessionPsychologicalEvaluation', { path: '/psychologicalevaluation' }, function () {
                this.resource('ccprPracticeSessionPsychologicalEvaluationMnhds', { path: '/mnhd' });
                this.resource('ccprPracticeSessionPsychologicalEvaluationMnhd', { path: '/mnhd/:ebed_questionaire_id' });
                this.resource('ccprPracticeSessionPsychologicalEvaluationHadss', { path: '/hads' });
                this.resource('ccprPracticeSessionPsychologicalEvaluationHads', { path: '/hads/:ebed_questionaire_id' });
                this.resource('ccprPracticeSessionPsychologicalEvaluationDs14s', { path: '/ds14' });
                this.resource('ccprPracticeSessionPsychologicalEvaluationDs14', { path: '/ds14/:ebed_questionaire_id' });
            });
            this.resource('ccprPracticeSessionNutritionalAdvice', { path: '/nutritionaladvice' }, function () {
                this.resource('ccprPracticeSessionNutritionalAdviceBmi', { path: '/bmi/:ebed_nutritionBmi_id' });
                this.resource('ccprPracticeSessionNutritionalAdviceDietContact', { path: '/dietcontact/:ebed_dietContact_id' });
            });
            this.route('decision', { path: '/decision' });
            this.resource('ccprPracticeSessionApprovals', { path: '/approvals' }, function () {
                this.resource('ccprPracticeSessionApproval', { path: '/:erevalidatie_approval_id' });
            });
        });
    });
    this.resource('ccprCardioArticles', { path: "/cardioarticles" });
    this.resource('ccprCardiologists', { path: "/cardiologists" });
    this.resource('ccprInfoSession', { path: "/infosession" }, function () {
        this.route('addPatient');
    });
    this.resource('ccprPatientPresence', { path: "/patientpresence" }, function () {
        this.route('index');
        this.route('addPatient');
    });
    this.resource('ccprPresenceOverview', { path: "/presenceoverview" });
    this.resource('ccprNextNutritionalAdvices', { path: "/nextnutritionaladvices" });
    this.resource('ccprParameter', { path: "/parameter" });
    this.resource('ccprListStaff', { path: "/liststaff" });
  });
}, true);
```

**It doesn't work**, only if I combine it with my solution, it works partialy.
I got errors like Assertion failed: The route ccprPracticeSession.info was not found 
and Uncaught Error: There is no route named ccprPracticeSession.info.index

Answer (score 1):

You could store all the route maps into another object, and then call `Router.map`, iterating through the maps. Something like,

```
App.RouteMapper = Ember.Object.extend({
});

App.RouteMapper.reopenClass({
  maps: null,

  map: function(callback, reassign) {
    if (!this.maps) this.maps = new Array();

    this.maps.push(callback);
    if (reassign) {
      this.assign();
    }
  },

  assign: function() {
    var self = this;
    App.Router.map(function() {
      var routerScope = this;
      self.maps.forEach(function(map) {
        map.call(routerScope);
      });
    });
  }
});

App.RouteMapper.map(function() {
  this.route('lorem');
  this.route('ipsum');
});
```

The sub module loaded code calls `App.RouteMapper.map` that would rebuild the entire set of routes from the maps stored. The `maps` are the same callbacks as you would pass to `Router.map` so that api wouldn't change.

Comment: Your solution is usefull to split up the router map. But that's not exactly what I mean. If you have a menu, all the router maps in the menu must be loaded at startup, but I want to async load the routes behind these router maps (Ember will have generated dummy ones and will have registered them in his container).

Comment: Though the `RouteMapper` works by splitting the maps, it preserves the map callbacks. So you can call the `RouteMapper.map` N times from inside code in an external submodule, and with 2nd reassign parameter, rebuild the routes, as well. The actual `RouteMapper.map` call can be anywhere, not necessarily inside the main app. That's just where you'll have the initial routes. See [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/oqogiw/1/edit). The adding routes is on button clicks here but could also be inside submodules.